# Como podría generar numeros en una cola sin que se repitan?

Tags: java

Cómo podria agregar numeros en una cola sin repetir

```
  package colae3;

   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ColaE3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Cola ObjCola = new Cola(10);
        int aleatorio = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            ObjCola.add(aleatorio);
        }
        System.out.println("LOS ELEMENTOS SON:");
        while (!ObjCola.Empty().equals(true)) {
            System.out.println(ObjCola.Poll());
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Cómo está definida la clase `Cola`? Edita tu pregunta y añade esa info, por favor. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Este es un pequeño ejemplo de como podrías utilizarlo, he utilizado un ArrayList para hacer la lista en vez de la clase "ColaE3". Con estas variable estableces el mínimo y el máximo de los rangos para los números aleatorio que se van a crear y la cantidad de los números que quieras crear.

> Cuidado de que el numero máximo siempre sea mayor o igual a la cantidad de numero aleatorio que necesitas, porque si no, no habrá números suficiente para llenar la lista.

```
int max=10;
int min=0;
int cantidad = 10;
```

Creamos una variable auxiliar y creamos la lista en la que vamos a añadir los numeros.

```
boolean existe=false;
ArrayList<Integer> cola= new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Creas un numero aleatorio inicial y lo añades a la lista

```
int aleatorio=(int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
cola.add(aleatorio);
```

El procedimiento:

```
while(cola.size()<=cantidad) {
    // Crear numero aleatorio
    aleatorio=(int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
   
    // Compruebas que el nuevo numero generado no este en la lista
    for(int j=0; j<cola.size(); j++) {
       if(aleatorio==cola.get(j)) {
           existe=true;
           break;
       }
          
   }
    
  if(existe) {
    // Si existe no haces nada y reseteas la busqueda
      existe=false;
  }else {
      // Si no existe lo añades a la lista
      cola.add(aleatorio);
      
  }
  
}
```

Y para comprobar imprimimos la lista:

```
for(int i=0; i<cola.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(cola.get(i));
}
```